# Format message by calling a written python function name in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.7, eval

I have functions

```
def getName():
   name = "Mark"
   return name

def getDay():
   day = "Tuesday"
   return day
```

I have a variable

`message = "Hi there [getName] today is [getDay]"`

I need to check all occurences for the strings between the square brackets in my `message` variable and check whether that name is a function that exists so that I can evaluate the value returned by the function and finally come up with a new message string as follows

```
message = "Hi there Mark, today is Tuesday
```

Comment: Just FYI, doing something like this in actual code is likely to be a security risk. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: You can call the variables and if they are not functions, they will return with error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459329/how-to-determine-if-the-variable-is-a-function-in-python?lq=1

Comment: @Mous thank you I will be waiting. Most likely the original ```message``` variable will be called from a database record. And if this way poses a security risk. How else would you go about to solve such a problem?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way of achieving this if you specifically want to use the string in that format. However, fstrings as shown in the above answer are a much superior alternative.

```
def f(message):
    returned_value=''
    m_copy=message
    while True:
        if '[' in m_copy:
            returned_value+=m_copy[:m_copy.index('[')]
            returned_value+=globals()[m_copy[m_copy.index('[')+1:m_copy.index(']')]]()
            m_copy=m_copy[m_copy.index(']')+1:]
        else:
            return returned_value+m_copy
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(f"Hi there {getName()} today is {getDay()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

f-strings are the way to go on this but that wasn't the question. You could do it like this but I wouldn't advise it:

```
import re

def getName():
    return 'Mark'

def getDay():
    return 'Tuesday'

msg = "Hi there [getName] today is [getDay]"

for word in re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', msg):
    try:
        msg = msg.replace(word, globals()[word[1:-1]]())
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass

print(msg)
```

**Output:**

```
Hi there Mark today is Tuesday
```

Comment: Thank you for the option, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

message = "Hi there [getName] today is [getDay]"
b = re.findall(r'\[.*?\]',message)
s=[]
for i in b:
    s.append(i.strip('[]'))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
['getName', 'getDay']
```

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question. But thanks for taking your time :-)

Comment: This is to find all the strings in the square brackets as was asked.